# Launch activity with startActivityForResult in a service

Tags: java, android, service, static, android-activity

I have a problem with startActivityForResult function.

I have an actity MqttClientActivity

```
public class MqttClientActivity extends Activity {

    static final int ACTIVATION_REQUEST = 47; // identifies our request id

    private static Context context;

    static DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager;
    static ComponentName demoDeviceAdmin;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        MqttClientActivity.context = getApplicationContext();

        // Initialize Device Policy Manager service and our receiver class
        devicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
        demoDeviceAdmin = new ComponentName(this, DemoDeviceAdminReceiver.class);
    }

    public static void test() {
        boolean active = devicePolicyManager.isAdminActive(demoDeviceAdmin);
        if (active) {
                         //do something...
        }
        else {
            // Activate device administration
            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
            intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN,
                    demoDeviceAdmin);
            intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,
                    "Your boss told you to do this");
            startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVATION_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}
```

And I have this class :

https://github.com/dobermai/android-mqtt-push/blob/master/src/de/eclipsemagazin/mqtt/push/MQTTService.java

then :

https://github.com/dobermai/android-mqtt-push/blob/master/src/de/eclipsemagazin/mqtt/push/PushCallback.java

In this latter class, in the messageArrived function I want to call my test function (MqttClientActivity), how I can do this? I have already set the function to static and variables "devicePolicyManager" and "demoDeviceAdmin" to static, but I can't launch the activty...

Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First, you cannot call `startActivityForResult()` from a `Service`. At best, you can call `startActivity()` from a `Service`.

Second, you cannot call `startActivity()` (or `startActivityForResult()`) from a `static` method, except by calling that on a `Context` (or `Activity` for `startActivityForResult()`), as those are not `static` methods.

Comment: But i must retrieve the result of the activity, this is why I must use startActivityForResult(). (I want to know if the user accepted to use the device administrator)

Comment: @user2021346: Then you should be calling `startActivityForResult()` on your `Activity`, in response to user input (or the launch of that activity).

Comment: Ok in the activity : is it correct to declare static variables? Because with static variables I can't call startactivityforresult...

Comment: @user2021346: "is it correct to declare static variables? " -- I do not know what you mean. Putting an `Activity` itself in a static data member results in a memory leak. More importantly, you seem to think that interrupting the user, in the middle of whatever the user is doing, by popping up an activity based on an MQTT push message is a good idea. Users are likely to disagree with you. That is particularly true for a "hey, make me a device admin" activity -- users will view this as being a sure sign that you are a malware author. Launch `ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN` *in response to user input*.